# Setting Cursor.Current has no effect in a Drag/Drop Helper Class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms application that allows drag/drop between ListViews. For consistency across the application, I created a DragDropHelper class that handles subscribing to the ItemDrag, DragOver, GiveFeedback, and DragDrop events. The functionality works fine, except for the setting of a custom cursor in the GiveFeedback event.

My DragDropHelper.GiveFeedback event handler is very basic (remember, this code is in a DragDropHelper class):

```
public void GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (mDragCursor == null) return;

    // We want our own icon as the cursor
    e.UseDefaultCursors = false;
    Cursor.Current = this.mDragCursor;            
}
```

I have confirmed that the GiveFeedback event is being triggered, and that the Cursor.Current line is being executed, but it has no effect on the Current.Cursor value. It's as if the system is ignoring me.

Now, if I copy/paste this same code into my Form.cs code itself, it works fine. So my question is: Can you wrap the drag/drop operations in a helper class and can you set the Cursor.Current from such a class?

Note that I've also tried setting the ListView.Cursor in the GiveFeedback handler but to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

You set the e.Effects property:

```
e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
```

Comment: I am setting e.Effect in the DragEnter event handler. In the GiveFeedback handler, e.Effect is ReadOnly.